# Calculating overestimate of displacement for the velocity curve $v(t)=10+5t-t^2$ (more information in body)

Tags: calculus, integration

Im a little confused on how I do this question [link to question here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l0ge3.jpg)

The question gives a velocity time function $(v(t)=10+5t-t^2)$ and asks to find the displacement using an overestimate U5 (find the overstimate using $5$ rectangles). However, the confusing part is that the question states 'assume the velocity after each one second time interval is constant'. This confuses me because, $f(2)=16 f(2.5)=16.25$ and $f(3)=16$, and I dont know if I should be using $16.25$ for the overestimate.

Does the [image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aI0Pz.jpg) accurately represent what the overestimate would look like according to the question? or would the middle rectangle touch $16.25 f(2.5)$ as that is the largest number between the interval 2 and 3. The main cofusion is coming from the wording of the question 'You need to find the displacement of the vehicle after $5$ seconds by assuming that the velocity of the vehicle is constant over
each one second time interval.'

Take a read of the question carefully and tell me what you think the overstimate U5 should be, for me its either $76$units^2 or $76.25$units^2.

$f(1)+f(2)+f(3)+f(3)+f(4)=76$
or
$f(1)+f(2)+f(2.5)+f(3)+f(4)=76.25$

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is just the wording that is confusing you. The problem has given you a velocity function, $v(t)$, and asked you to (over) estimate the distance traveled (the displacement) after $5$ seconds. The distance traveled is $\displaystyle \int_0^5 v(t) \;dt$. But of course, it wants an estimate so you will use the area of rectangles to approximate this integral. It wants an overestimate using the maximum value over each interval. [Try plotting the function](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%2010%2B5*t-t%5E2%20for%20t%3D0%20to%20t%3D5) $v(t)$.

What is the maximum value of $v(t)$ for each of the intervals? For $t \in [0,1]$, notice $v(1)$ is the largest value. For $t \in [1,2]$, $v(2)$ is the largest value. For $t \in [4,5]$, $v(4)$ is the largest value. The only question is what is the largest value for $t \in [2,3]$? [Hint: This is  a parabola, and the largest value for $v(t)$ in $[2,3]$ is clearly the 'turning point' of the parabola.] Then you have
$$
\text{Distance Traveled}= \text{Area under curve} \approx \sum lw= v(1) \cdot 1 + v(2) \cdot 1 + v(?) \cdot 1 + v(3) \cdot 1 + v(4) \cdot 1 
$$ 
I leave you to find the $t$ value you need to plug into $v(t)$ to find the largest $v(t)$ value over the interval $[2,3]$, and to find the other values and the sum. I will help with one value to show the process. We have $v(1)= 10+5-1=14$ so the first number in the sum is $14 \cdot 1=14$.

Comment: Thank you, i totally get the explanation and the process, the thing is the question states 'assume the velocity of the vehicle is constant over each one second time interval.' So while t=2.5 is the turning point of the parabola (hence the largest velocity at 16.25m/s), my question is does the question want us to assume that the velocity stays constant between the interval [2, 3] thus v(2.5)=v(2)=v(3)=16.

Comment: @JosephElShafei Because this is the only way you can justify the rectangle approximation. I think you are worried about the fact that you are using a velocity 'in the middle' of the interval. But you are already assuming the velocity is constant when you use something like $v(1)$. So when you use $v(1) \cdot 1$ for the first rectangle, you have assumed the velocity is constant (at velocity $v(1)$) for the interval $[0,1]$. You do the same for $[2,3]$, it's just that the this maximum velocity occurs in the interior of the interval.